# What is the difference in these queries

Tags: mysql

## Problem :

Whats the Diff ... in these Query  ... when Tables are

I used table aliases here i believe there is no mistake

```
------------------------ Tables -------------------
mysql> select * from college;
+----------+-------+------------+
| cName    | state | enrollment |
+----------+-------+------------+
| Stanford | CA    |      15000 |
| Berkeley | CA    |      36000 |
| MIT      | MA    |      10000 |
| Cornell  | NY    |      21000 |
+----------+-------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from apply;
+-----+----------+----------------+----------+
| sID | cName    | major          | decision |
+-----+----------+----------------+----------+
| 123 | Berkeley | CS             | Y        |
| 123 | Cornell  | EE             | Y        |
| 123 | Stanford | CS             | Y        |
| 123 | Stanford | EE             | N        |
| 234 | Berkeley | biology        | N        |
| 345 | Cornell  | bioengineering | N        |
| 345 | Cornell  | CS             | Y        |
| 345 | Cornell  | EE             | N        |
| 345 | MIT      | bioengineering | Y        |
| 543 | MIT      | CS             | N        |
| 678 | Stanford | history        | Y        |
| 765 | Cornell  | history        | N        |
| 765 | Cornell  | psychology     | Y        |
| 765 | Stanford | history        | Y        |
| 876 | MIT      | biology        | Y        |
| 876 | MIT      | marine biology | N        |
| 876 | Stanford | CS             | N        |
| 987 | Berkeley | CS             | Y        |
| 987 | Stanford | CS             | Y        |
+-----+----------+----------------+----------+
19 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

----------------- 2 Almost Same Queries : But Diff. Outputs -----------------

```
mysql> Select c.cname from College c,Apply a where  c.cname=a.cname  and enrollment > 20000 and major='CS';
+---------+
| cname   |
+---------+
| Cornell |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

  ----------------------> only One row

mysql>
mysql> select college.cname from college,apply where college.cname = apply.cname and enrollment > 20000 and major = 'CS';
+----------+
| cname    |
+----------+
| Berkeley |
| Cornell  |
| Berkeley |
+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

 WHILE -------------------------> three rows
```

Comment: `from college,apply` <-- This way to write joins is deprecated since about 25 years. Consider using proper joins.

Comment: tell me the correct way plz...

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 different tables College and college so you are getting the different outputs.
If you would have used College instead of college then you would have got the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Those two queries are using totally different tables.

In MySQL identifiers are case sensitive. That means that table `College` is NOT the same table as `college`.

Comment: Good catch ! The same for `Apply` and `apply`

Comment: but in that Database ,only one table having that type of name is there and i.e. College

Comment: @shubhamsrivastava Can you create the example in SQL Fiddle? --> https://www.db-fiddle.com/  Choose your version of MySQL. This way we can run it and test it right away.